# Нужна помощь с кодом битрикса

Tags: php, html, битрикс

В общем нужно было добавить в шапку некоторые блоки, отредактировал код через админку, а редактор кода "натворил" дел с ним, и теперь стили не подключаются. Не могу разобраться, вроде ничего лишнего в коде нет, но ничего не работает.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем дело? Вот сам код:

```html
<?if(!defined( "B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>


  <?$curPage=$ GLOBALS[ 'APPLICATION']->GetCurPage(false);?>



    <?if(isset($_GET[ 'PAGEN_1']) || ($_GET[ 'set_filter']=='Y' )) $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("robots", "noindex, follow");?>

      <?{echo SITE_SERVER_NAME;}?><span class="bxhtmled-surrogate-inner"><span class="bxhtmled-right-side-item-icon"></span><span class="bxhtmled-comp-lable" unselectable="on" spellcheck="false">Код PHP</span></span>";

        <?CJSCore::Init(array( "jquery"));?>
          <?$APPLICATION->ShowHead();?>
            <?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?><span class="bxhtmled-surrogate-inner"><span class="bxhtmled-right-side-item-icon"></span><span class="bxhtmled-comp-lable" unselectable="on" spellcheck="false">Код PHP</span></span>/css/style.css";
              <?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?><span class="bxhtmled-surrogate-inner"><span class="bxhtmled-right-side-item-icon"></span><span class="bxhtmled-comp-lable" unselectable="on" spellcheck="false">Код PHP</span></span>/css/slicknav.min.css";
                <!--script src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/js/jquery.js"></script-->
                <script src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
                <script src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/js/jcarousel.js"></script>
                <script src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/js/fancy.js"></script>
                <script src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/js/phone.js"></script>
                <script src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/js/script.js"></script>
                <script src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/js/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>
                <script src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/js/stickUp.min.js"></script>
                <!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src="#BXPHP_18#/js/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

                <div id="panel">
                  <?$APPLICATION->ShowPanel();?></div>
                <!-- Верх шаблона -->
                <div class="h">
                  <div class="mid">
                    <a href="/" class="h_logo left">
                      <img width="154" src="/bitrix/templates/umeta-magaz/images/logo.png" height="58" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <div class="h_tel_block left">
                      <div class="h_t">Телефон:</div>
                      <div class="h_tel">+7 (812) 407-31-12</div>
                      <div class="h_tel">+7 (921) 893-77-49</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="h_data_block left">
                      <div class="h_t">Консультации и обработка заказов</div>
                      <div class="h_data h_data_work">С 8:00 до 20:00 МСК</div>
                      <div class="h_data h_data_mail"><a href="mailto:sale@u-78.ru">sale@u-78.ru</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="h_cart right rt">
                      <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent( "bitrix:sale.basket.basket.line", ".default", Array( "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => ".default", "HIDE_ON_BASKET_PAGES" => "Y", "PATH_TO_BASKET" => SITE_DIR."personal/cart/", "PATH_TO_ORDER" => SITE_DIR."personal/order/make/",
                        "PATH_TO_PERSONAL" => SITE_DIR."personal/", "PATH_TO_PROFILE" => SITE_DIR."personal/", "PATH_TO_REGISTER" => SITE_DIR."auth/", "POSITION_FIXED" => "N", "SHOW_AUTHOR" => "Y", "SHOW_EMPTY_VALUES" => "Y", "SHOW_NUM_PRODUCTS" => "Y",
                        "SHOW_PERSONAL_LINK" => "N", "SHOW_PRODUCTS" => "N", "SHOW_TOTAL_PRICE" => "Y" ) );?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <nav class="h_menu_block">
                    <div class="mid">
                      <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent( "bitrix:menu", "top", Array( "ALLOW_MULTI_SELECT" => "N", "CHILD_MENU_TYPE" => "", "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => ".default", "DELAY" => "N", "MAX_LEVEL" => "1", "MENU_CACHE_GET_VARS" => "", "MENU_CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
                        "MENU_CACHE_TYPE" => "A", "MENU_CACHE_USE_GROUPS" => "Y", "MENU_THEME" => "", "ROOT_MENU_TYPE" => "top", "USE_EXT" => "N" ) );?>
                        <div class="prim-menu">

                          <div class="h_data h_data_mail"><a href="mailto:sale@u-78.ru">sale@u-78.ru</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </nav>
                </div>
                <div class="n mid">
                  <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent( "bitrix:search.form", "search", Array( "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => ".default", "PAGE" => "#SITE_DIR#search/index.php" ) );?>
                </div>
                <!-- Тело страницы -->


                <?$curPage=$ GLOBALS[ 'APPLICATION']->GetCurPage($get_index_page=false); if (($curPage == SITE_DIR)) { $APPLICATION->IncludeFile( SITE_DIR."include/main_catalog.php", Array(), Array("MODE"=>"php") ); } else { $APPLICATION->IncludeFile( SITE_DIR."include/catalog.php", Array(),
                  Array("MODE"=>"php") ); }?>
```

Сайт, который сломался: http://u-78.ru/

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Для начала почитайте как в Битриксе подключаются скрипты и стили. И вот это `<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?><span class="bxhtmled-surrogate-inner"><span class="bxhtmled-right-side-item-icon"></span><span class="bxhtmled-comp-lable" unselectable="on" spellcheck="false">Код PHP</span></span>/css/style.css";
              <?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?><span class="bxhtmled-surrogate-inner"><span class="bxhtmled-right-side-item-icon"></span><span class="bxhtmled-comp-lable" unselectable="on" spellcheck="false">Код PHP</span></span>/css/slicknav.min.css";` Вас не смущает?

Comment: Смущает, но не пойму, откуда спаны в подключении.

Comment: сами они появиться просто так не могли. Переписывайте код.

Comment: А можете, пожалуйста, написать пример подключения стиля?

Comment: <link href="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH;?>/css/style.css" /> ?

Comment: `<?
// для js-файлов
$APPLICATION->AddHeadScript('/bitrix/templates/.default/additional.js');

// для css-файлов
$APPLICATION->SetAdditionalCSS("/bitrix/templates/.default/additional.css");
?>` Базовые скрипты Битрикса подключаются через `$APPLICATION->ShowHead()` - это у Вас должно быть обязательно. Но прежде чем лезть кодить в Битриксе почитайте [курсы](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/index.php), и посмотрите [видео](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/index.php#tab-dev-link)

Comment: в <?=..?> не нужна в конце точка с запятой. т.е. <link href="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/css/style.css" />